# Why is the iron inter-system crossing non-negligible at high temperatures?

Tags: physical-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, spectroscopy, uv-vis-spectroscopy

Inter-system crossing (ISC) is a radiationless process involving forbidden transitions between singlet and triplet state. These are more common with heavy atom molecules, so I understand that ISC is dependent on the atomic number.

How does the temperature influence the ISC? Is this related to activation energy? Is the ISC rate coefficient temperature-dependent?

Comment: Nothing forbidden about the ISC. The direct radiative transition from and to the triplet state is forbidden, hence its long lifetime (phosphorecence).

Comment: @Karl It is a forbidden transition in the sense that purely electronic selection rules don't allow such transitions. to OP: Intersystem crossing needs an overlap between vibrational/nuclear wavefunctions as well as the multiplets energy should match, therefore the termal occupation of the vibrational levels of the given electronic states will influence the transition probability.

Comment: @Greg Well its not even a real transition, because there is no energy transfer. ISC occurs into a vibrationally excited state, and is directly followed by lattice relaxation into the triplett ground state. The picture of a the ISC being "forbidden" and therefore having a low probability is very misleading.